# How to get output values in bash array by calling other program from bash?

Tags: bash

I am stuck with a peculiar situation, where in from python I am printing two strings one by one and reading it in bash script (which calls the python code piece)
I am expecting array size to be 2, but somehow, bash considers spaces also as a element separator and return me size of 3.

Example scripts

multi_line_return.py file has following content

```
print("foo bar")
print(5)
```

multi_line_call.sh has following content

```
#!/bin/bash

PYTHON_EXE="ABSOLUTE_PATH TO PYTHON EXECUTABLE IN LINUX"
CURR_DIR=$(cd $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}) && pwd)/

array=()
while read line ; do
  array+=($line)
done < <(${PYTHON_EXE} ${CURR_DIR}multi_line_return.py)

echo "array length --> ${#array[@]}"
echo "each variable in new line"
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    printf $i
    printf "\n"
done
```

Now keep both of the above file in same directory and make following call to see result.

```
bash multi_line_call.sh
```

As you can see in result,

```
I am getting 
  array length = 3  
  1.foo, 2.bar & 3. 5

The expectation is 
One complete line of python output (stdout) as one element of bash array
  array length = 2
  1. foo bar & 2. 5
```

Comment: Your Python program does not contain any function. It just outputs something to stdout. It seems to me that you are searching for a way to store the stdout of a program into a bash array, one line in one array element. If this is what you want to achieve, please update your question to make this clear. In this case, your question has nothing to do with Python, because it applies to every program which generates a stdout, so please remove the Python tags then. Also, your 'shell' tag does not apply here, because POSIX shell does not have arrays.

Comment: Sure, I want one complete line in one array, I will put it in expected section. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put quotes around `$line` to prevent it from being split:

```
array+=("$line")
```

You can also do it without a loop using `readarray`:

```
readarray array < <(${PYTHON_EXE} ${CURR_DIR}multi_line_return.py)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I have tried both of above, it only prints foo and bar is left out.

Comment: Sorry, I had extra spaces.